# Querying my database to display only a specific category list from Joomla mod_XpertScroller

Tags: php, database, joomla

I have a Joomla website at Brandroot(.)com. On the the homepage you can see in the middle two different sliders, one of them **Featured Brand Names** and the other **Recently Added Brand Names**.

If you go to the **Brands** page you will see on the right site a list of category specific pages, which display domain names that are added in the backend to that category.

What I need is to create a slider like the ones on the homepage that displays only the domains that are in the category, **4 Letter**.

I already have the basic code done that allows you to select the 4 letter option for the slider:

[image]

This is the code for the `switch` that controls the options for the sliders:

```
switch($filtering){
    case 1://Recently Added
        $query->where('a.sold = 0');
        break;
    case 2://Recently Sold
        $query->where('a.sold = 1');
        break;
    case 3://Featured Top
        $query->where('a.featured = 1');
        $query->where('a.sold = 0');
        break;
    case 4://4 Letter Domains
        /*
        $query->where('a.featured = 1');
        $query->where('a.sold = 0');
        */
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

I need help trying to figure out what code needs to be in `case 4:`.

Here is the database query code I believe to be handling the filtering for the options:

```
function &getList(&$params){
    $db = & JFactory::getDBO();
    $filtering = $params->get('filtering');

    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select('a.*');
    $query->from('#__brands as a');
    $query->where('a.state = 1');
```

Here's a snapshot of the table being accessed.

[image]

I have no idea what to write to filter just the `4 letter` category. Please help me with patience as I am trying to do this myself to save money. Please let me know if anything else is required to help you help solve this.

Comment: are you using the Joomla 1.5 or 2.5 module?

Comment: @Lodder How do I find that out?

Comment: well, are you using Joomla 1.5 or 2.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that the domain is stored in `title`, this will do it:

```
case 4: //4 Letter Domains
    $query->where('CHAR_LENGTH(a.title) = 4');
    break;
```